# Failing to launch tensorboard from jupyter

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tensorboard

I get the error below when I try launching `tensorboard` from my `jupyter notebook`. I am using a `conda environment` and using the env-specific kernel since `tensorflow` is only installed in my environment. What am I doing wrong?

The error:

```
%tensorboard --logdir logs

ERROR: Failed to launch TensorBoard (exited with -6).
Contents of stderr:
[libprotobuf ERROR external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:393] Invalid file descriptor data passed to EncodedDescriptorDatabase::Add().
[libprotobuf FATAL external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:1367] CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type google::protobuf::FatalException: CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size):
```

**EDIT**

I have the problem even when I try launching from the terminal (inside my `conda env`):

```
tensorboard --logdir = 'logs/'

[libprotobuf ERROR external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:393] Invalid file descriptor data passed to EncodedDescriptorDatabase::Add().
[libprotobuf FATAL external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:1367] CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type google::protobuf::FatalException: CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the following solution. Apparently this is a specific issue that occurs when running `macOS Catalina`, and can be solved by switching to `protobuf version 3.8.0`. So basically uninstalling `tensorflow` and `protobuf` and re-installing with `protobuf = 3.8.0`. I found this answer [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33746), check it out for further info.

Comment: I tried installing `protobuf version 3.8.0`, but still get the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62342221/tensorboard-logdir-runs-not-working-abort-trap-6/62342631#62342631

Comment: Have you made sure that you've properly re-installed `protobuf`? List your packages and see if it says `protobuf 3.8.0`.

Comment: Yes, `protobuf` is correctly installed:
`Name: protobuf. 
Version: 3.8.0. 
Summary: Protocol Buffers. 
Home-page: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/. 
Author: None. 
Author-email: None.   
License: 3-Clause BSD License. 
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages. 
Requires: six, setuptools. 
Required-by: tensorflow, tensorboard. `

Comment: And `tensorflow`/`tensorboard` versions are `2.0.0`?

Comment: `tensorflow: Version: 2.2.0`, and `tensorboard: Version: 2.2.2`

Comment: Ok try going back to `2.0.0` if you can. Those are the versions that worked for me. And note that I uninstalled both `ternsorflow` and `protobuf` before reinstalling.

Answer (score 1):

`conda update protobuf` solved it for me. I assume you can also use pip the upgrade, but I didn't try