# tensorboard --logdir=runs not working: Abort trap: 6

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorboard, abort

I am trying to run tensorboard: `tensorboard --logdir=runs`.
I have also tried: `tensorboard --logdir=runs --host=127.0.0.1`.
I am running the command from the terminal from within the the directory, which contains the `runs` folder.

I get the following error:

```
[libprotobuf FATAL external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:1367] 
CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type google::protobuf::FatalException: 
CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
Abort trap: 6
```

My Python code contains the following lines:

```
tb_path = './runs/SimpleLSTM_MNIST'
if os.path.isdir(tb_path):
    shutil.rmtree(tb_path)

writer = tb.SummaryWriter(log_dir=tb_path)
```

My `runs` folder contains the folder `SimpleLSTM_MNIST`, which contains `events.out.tfevents.1591953948.computername.local.29440.0`.

Operating System: `MacOS Catalina`

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: I tried installing `protobuf version 3.8.0`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60028929/failing-to-launch-tensorboard-from-jupyter), but still get the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a specific issue that occurs when running `macOS Catalina`, and can be solved by switching to `protobuf version 3.8.0` and tensorflow version `2.0.0`.
So basically uninstalling `tensorflow` and `protobuf` and re-installing with `pip3 install protobuf==3.8.0` and `pip3 install tensorflow==2.0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

looks like protobuf is not working properly,
try install latest version

```
pip3 uninstall protobuf
pip3 install protobuf
```